# Client is recognizing Content-Type even after commenting out explicit Content-Type declaration

Tags: servlets, content-type, http-caching, response-headers

This is my hello-world application I just wrote.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");   //Line1
//  response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");  # Line-AAA
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    //out.print("Good days are here :)");
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
  //  out.println("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1/>");
    out.println("<title>servlet demo");
    out.println("</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>Helloworld");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT");    //Line2
}
```

Here initially I hadn't written Line-AAA and hence the webpage was not getting displayed properly as is obvious and later I added the line and everything worked perfectly.

But later i tried commenting out #Line-AAA  and found that it has no effect even after server restart. Searching on stackoverflow i found two solutionsto disable caching in Line1 and Line2 ,but both doesn't seem to work. Page is getting displayed properly even after commenting out Line-AAA.

It apparently doesn't create any problem for me at the moment, but I am curious to know how to properly stop this caching.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you clear browser cache? See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/49547

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I tried that too. Still to no avail. Actually i opened in different browsers , still no effect. Sorry for late reply, was travelling